# How to get the date a xml file was signed digitally using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, digital-signature

I need to know if there is a way to get the date a xml file was signed digitally. Not the date of the certificate.

I have searched on google, but the examples return the date of the certificate. I don't know is the encrypted part includes a timestamp field.

Comment: Possible to post Signature value ?  If it is CMS signature or contains signature properties then it may have time of signing...